# Login problems on lan virtual host

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, lan

I created a virtual host on a machine, and I am able to access it on another machine, but then I can't login into the application I was working on from another machine, but I can view the login screen.... I don't now what the problem is and its puzzling me.
I'm using PHP 5 and MySQL. The settings on the virtual host are as follows.

```
<VirtualHost 10.52.2.211:80>ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName piet.moyatech
ServerAlias piet.moyatech
DocumentRoot /var/www/piet.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/piet.local>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's puzzling us more with this description.

Comment: Sorry... I really don't know how to phrase the question but let met try. Theres an application that I'm implementing on machine A, and it works properly on that machine. Now I decided to test it from a different machine through LAN and I was able to connect to the application from the other machine, but it fails to login into the application from that machine or any other that I have tried.

Comment: And you think with our crystal ball we can now guess everything about the authentication/authorization methods in place, the LAN layouts, the firewall settings, the Apache vhost configuration etc.? With the information you've given so far the question boils down to *"My car doesn't work, please help"*. There's no way anyone can help or even take a guess at the problem without taking a look or a LOT more information from your end.

Comment: Its a PHP and MySQL application on a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I finally figured out what I did wrong. I had created the virtual host but I hadn't added it to apache's enable sites. Thanks for your help :-)